# Invalid use of incomplete type, reference vs pointer

Tags: c++, g++

Code below compiles and works both in Visual Studio and g++:

```
class A;
A* getRef(void);
char (&func(...))[2];

int main() {
    bool isDefault = sizeof(func(getRef()))==2;
    std::cout << isDefault << std::endl; //prints 1
    return 0;
}
```

Next code still compiles (and works) in Studio, but g++ states this is `invalid use of incomplete type 'class A'`:

```
class A;
A& getRef(void); //the only change
char (&func(...))[2];

int main() {

    bool isDefault = sizeof(func(getRef()))==2; //g++ error here
    std::cout << isDefault << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is this a fundamentally wrong code which should be rejected by a compiler (and if so, why VS compiler doesn't produce any warnings)? Or is there actually some difference between pointers and references in this context that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @Franck, the OP is not trying to get `sizeof(A&)`. `A&` is an argument to `func`.

Comment: @RSahu Sorry, I missed the `func` call.

Comment: @RSahu: But the reference (to incomplete type) is used as actual argument for an ellipsis argument. And that makes it a bit subtle.

Comment: I think both compilers evaluate isDefault as `sizeof(char[2])` at compile-time. But g++ should generate an Abstract Syntax Tree for the expression `func(getRef())` that emits the error, even if the expression is forgotten at the end.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, Agreed. It's not clear to me whether the standard dictates that the arguments to `func` **must** be evaluated to come up with the value of `sizeof(func(getRef()))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crucial aspect of the modified code is that a reference to incomplete type is passed as actual argument to an ellipsis formal argument.

*C++11 §5.2.2/7, about arguments to ellipsis:*

> **”** The lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and
>   function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are performed on the argument expression. An argument that has (possibly cv-qualified) type `std::nullptr_t` is converted to type `void*` (4.10). After these conversions, if the argument does not have arithmetic, enumeration, pointer, pointer to member, or class type, the program is ill-formed.

Then for the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, we find

*C++11 §4.1/1:*

> **”** A glvalue (3.10) of a non-function, non-array type `T` can be converted to a prvalue. If `T` is an incomplete type, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed.

As I read it, but this is just my gut-feeling interpretation, a reference to `T` is a glvalue of type `T`, which here is incomplete, yielding ill-formed code.

Answer (score 2):

No matter what the arguments to `func` are `sizeof(func(getRef()))` is going to be equal to `2`. The arguments to `func` need not be evaluated to come up with that answer.

From the C++11 Standard:

> **5.3.3 Sizeof**
>
> 1 The `sizeof` operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand. The operand is either an expression, which is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5), or a parenthesized *type-id*.

In your case, the operand is an expression, which is an unevaluated operand. The compiler need not evaluate `func(getRef())` to come up with the value of `sizeof(func(getRef()))`.

Hence, I conclude that `g++` is overreaching in what it needs.

---

It appears that g++'s handling of variable argument functions is the culprit. It works fine when `func` is modified to be

```
char (&func(A&))[2];
```

See it working at http://ideone.com/YQD9v0.

Comment: Well, that kind of defeats the initial purpose of the code (to declare `char func(A&)` and thus find out if `A` is a complete type). Thanks for the input, though.